# Include the cancel package for LaTeX

Tags: feature-request, mathjax

In explaining derivations and proofs, it is really handy to show terms that go to zero or cancel with each other.

Is it possible to include the [cancel package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/cancel.html) or something equivalent in the MathJax install?

Comment: See this http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-users/browse_thread/thread/b6e1479f71244a27

Comment: I'm not sure if the SE team supports adding additional LaTeX packages to the MathJax installation. (If they do, `cancel` would be just one of a long list of packages that would be useful to us.)

Comment: @David: Of course you're right. It would have to be done by the SE team and would be useful in their other sites. I put the question here as a single item wishlist!

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the thread. So it would be comparatively simple to add a basic *strikethrough* to the MathJax setup...

Comment: @David, @Simon. This kind of stuff wouldn't be done by the SE team but by the MathJax team. They already said that 'cancel' is in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, that's good to know.

Comment: Use `\not`. It's esp. imp. in like Feyn. slash not. etc.